# crear pdf y descargar auto

Tags: c#, pdf

Logre realizar la creacion del pdf con itexsharp, e hice que se almacene en el disco d://.

Lo que deseo es que al ejecutar la funcion es que se descargue mediante el navegador a la carpeta de descarga

```
namespace Web.Controllers
{
    public class ReportePDFController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult pdfPL()
        {
            long n = Request.InputStream.Length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[n];
            Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(n));
            string parametro = Server.UrlDecode(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
            var data = JObject.Parse(parametro);
            String Titulo = "";
            String RazonSocial = "";
            String Referencia = "";
            String NumeroDocumento = "";
            String Subtotal = "";
            String igv = "";
            String Total = "";
            String DiaHoy = "";

            Titulo = (data["Titulo"]).ToString();
            RazonSocial = (data["RazonSocial"]).ToString();
            Referencia = (data["Referencia"]).ToString();
            NumeroDocumento = (data["NumeroDocumento"]).ToString();
            Subtotal = (data["Subtotal"]).ToString();
            igv = (data["igv"]).ToString();
            Total = (data["Total"]).ToString();
            DiaHoy = (data["DiaHoy"]).ToString();

            PdfPCell cell = null;

            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"D://" + NumeroDocumento + RazonSocial + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

            doc.AddTitle("Valorizacion de Servicio");
            doc.AddCreator("Bureau Veritas Perú");

            doc.Open();

            iTextSharp.text.Font fnt_titulo_tarifa = FontFactory.GetFont("ArialBold", BaseFont.CP1250, true, 16, iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE);
            iTextSharp.text.Font _standardFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
            iTextSharp.text.Font _headertable = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.WHITE);


            PdfPTable tblInicio = new PdfPTable(2);
            tblInicio.WidthPercentage = 100;

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(Titulo, fnt_titulo_tarifa));
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingTop = 25;
            tblInicio.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cliente : ", _standardFont));
            cell.Padding = 10;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 0;
            cell.PaddingTop = 25;
            cell.Border = 0;
            tblInicio.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(RazonSocial, _standardFont));
            cell.Padding = 10;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 0;
            cell.PaddingTop = 25;
            cell.Border = 0;
            tblInicio.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Referencia : ", _standardFont));
            cell.Padding = 10;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 0;
            cell.Border = 0;
            tblInicio.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(Referencia, _standardFont));
            cell.Padding = 10;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 0;
            cell.Border = 0;
            tblInicio.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Referencia Inspectoria : ", _standardFont));
            cell.Padding = 10;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 0;
            cell.Border = 0;
            tblInicio.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(NumeroDocumento, _standardFont));
            cell.Padding = 10;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 0;
            cell.Border = 0;
            tblInicio.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Fecha : ", _standardFont));
            cell.Padding = 10;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 20;
            cell.Border = 0;
            tblInicio.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(DiaHoy, _standardFont));
            cell.Padding = 10;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 20;
            cell.Border = 0;
            tblInicio.AddCell(cell);

            doc.Add(tblInicio);

            PdfPTable tblPL = new PdfPTable(8);
            tblPL.WidthPercentage = 100;

            PdfPCell clServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Servicio", _headertable));
            clServicio.BorderWidth = 0;
            clServicio.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
            clServicio.PaddingBottom = 5;
            clServicio.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(165, 0, 33);
            clServicio.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            PdfPCell clMaterial = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Material", _headertable));
            clMaterial.BorderWidth = 0;
            clMaterial.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
            clMaterial.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(165, 0, 33);
            clMaterial.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            PdfPCell clCalidad = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Calidad", _headertable));
            clCalidad.BorderWidth = 0;
            clCalidad.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
            clCalidad.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(165, 0, 33);
            clCalidad.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            PdfPCell clSubServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("SubServicio", _headertable));
            clSubServicio.BorderWidth = 0;
            clSubServicio.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
            clSubServicio.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(165, 0, 33);
            clSubServicio.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            PdfPCell clCantidad = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cantidad", _headertable));
            clCantidad.BorderWidth = 0;
            clCantidad.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
            clCantidad.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(165, 0, 33);
            clCantidad.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            PdfPCell clUm = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("UM", _headertable));
            clUm.BorderWidth = 0;
            clUm.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
            clUm.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(165, 0, 33);
            clUm.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            PdfPCell clMoneda = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Moneda", _headertable));
            clMoneda.BorderWidth = 0;
            clMoneda.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
            clMoneda.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(165, 0, 33);
            clMoneda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            PdfPCell clTarifa = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Tarifa", _headertable));
            clTarifa.BorderWidth = 0;
            clTarifa.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
            clTarifa.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(165, 0, 33);
            clTarifa.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            tblPL.AddCell(clServicio);
            tblPL.AddCell(clMaterial);
            tblPL.AddCell(clCalidad);
            tblPL.AddCell(clSubServicio);
            tblPL.AddCell(clCantidad);
            tblPL.AddCell(clUm);
            tblPL.AddCell(clMoneda);
            tblPL.AddCell(clTarifa);

            var servicios = JArray.Parse(data["Servicios"].ToString());

            foreach (JObject jServicios in servicios.Children<JToken>())
            {
                clServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(jServicios["Servicio"].ToString(), _standardFont));
                clServicio.BorderWidth = 0;
                clServicio.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
                clServicio.PaddingBottom = 5;
                clServicio.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                clMaterial = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(jServicios["Material"].ToString(), _standardFont));
                clMaterial.BorderWidth = 0;
                clMaterial.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
                clMaterial.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                clCalidad = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(jServicios["Calidad"].ToString(), _standardFont));
                clCalidad.BorderWidth = 0;
                clCalidad.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
                clCalidad.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                clSubServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(jServicios["SubServicio"].ToString(), _standardFont));
                clSubServicio.BorderWidth = 0;
                clSubServicio.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
                clSubServicio.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                clCantidad = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(jServicios["Cantidad"].ToString(), _standardFont));
                clCantidad.BorderWidth = 0;
                clCantidad.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
                clCantidad.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                clUm = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(jServicios["Um"].ToString(), _standardFont));
                clUm.BorderWidth = 0;
                clUm.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
                clUm.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                clMoneda = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(jServicios["Moneda"].ToString(), _standardFont));
                clMoneda.BorderWidth = 0;
                clMoneda.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
                clMoneda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                clTarifa = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(jServicios["Tarifa"].ToString(), _standardFont));
                clTarifa.BorderWidth = 0;
                clTarifa.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
                clTarifa.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                tblPL.AddCell(clServicio);
                tblPL.AddCell(clMaterial);
                tblPL.AddCell(clCalidad);
                tblPL.AddCell(clSubServicio);
                tblPL.AddCell(clCantidad);
                tblPL.AddCell(clUm);
                tblPL.AddCell(clMoneda);
                tblPL.AddCell(clTarifa);
            }

            doc.Add(tblPL);

            PdfPTable tblCosto = new PdfPTable(9);
            tblCosto.WidthPercentage = 100;

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("SUBTOTAL : ", _standardFont));
            cell.PaddingTop = 25;
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            cell.Colspan = 8;
            tblCosto.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(Subtotal, _standardFont));
            cell.PaddingTop = 25;
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            tblCosto.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("I.G.V. : ", _standardFont));
            cell.PaddingTop = 15;
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            cell.Colspan = 8;
            tblCosto.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(igv, _standardFont));
            cell.PaddingTop = 15;
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            tblCosto.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("TOTAL : ", _standardFont));
            cell.PaddingTop = 15;
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            cell.Colspan = 8;
            tblCosto.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(Total, _standardFont));
            cell.PaddingTop = 15;
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            tblCosto.AddCell(cell);

            doc.Add(tblCosto);


            doc.Close();

            writer.Close();

            return null;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes tu archivo guardado en alguna parte de tu disco solo necesitas obtenerla en algún Controller que se mande a llamar cuando el usuario acceda a esa liga.

La acción debe regresar un objeto de tipo **FileContentResult**.

```
    public ActionResult DownloadPdf()
    {
        string path = "Path a tu pdf";
        string nombreArchivo = "nombre de tu archivo pdf";


        var memory = new MemoryStream();

        using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, nombreArchivo), FileMode.Open))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memory);
        }

        memory.Position = 0;
        //aquí también puedes definir el nombre del archivo de descarga
        return File(memory, "application/pdf", nombreArchivo);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas maneras de hacer la descarga. Si ya tienes la ruta del archivo, lo más sencillo es cambiar la "firma" del método, en lugar de retornar un `ActionResult`, devuelve un `FileResult` y agrega el siguiente código al final:

```
public FileResult pdfPL()
{
    ... // Todo tu código
    doc.Close();
    writer.Close();        

    string archivo = NumeroDocumento + RazonSocial + ".pdf";
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{archivo}\"");
    return File(@"D://" + archivo, "application/pdf"));
}
```